# How to impute the std deviation of a sample using the pooled mean and standard deviation of similar samples?

Tags: variance, mean, standard-deviation, data-imputation, pooling

I want to perform a meta-regression based on the mean changes from baseline values.In one of the studies, the standard deviation has not been mentioned. How can I impute the value of the missed standard deviation? Can I take the pooled standard deviation of other studies as the standard deviation of this study? Or should I change the pooled standard deviation to fit the mean and sample size of this study?

Comment: If you want rigor, don’t use the study with the missing standard deviation.

Comment: Or derive it from other information which may have been published such as sample size and confidence interval